# Convert Iterable to Array using Guava

Tags: java, guava

I need to return a `String` array. I use Guava to split the `String`. Please see the code below

```
Iterable<String> arrayOfValues =  Splitter.on(";").split(myString);
```

it returns an `Iterable`. but i need a `String[]`. Is there are any way to give `Iterator< Element >` and  convert that to `Array[]`. Many Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use the [`Iterables.toArray(Iterable<? extends T> iterable, Class<T> type)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#toArray-java.lang.Iterable-java.lang.Class-) method in Guava.

Comment: Iterables#toArray is not public

Comment: do you know if is there a single code like like this but without guava?

Comment: @guai Just for benefit of others, Iterables.toArray without second parameter for type class is private. The method above with this parameter is public.

Comment: The conversion to arr [] is super slow. It takes away all the speed benefit you got.. for ex a 500k split loop (~300 values) which finished in 50ms finishes in about 6000ms when converted to arr []

Answer (score 22):

If you use the plain Java String.split(regex) method, you're fine. It returns a String[].

```
"my;string".split(";")

String[] splits = mystring.split(";");
```

Don't use fancy libraries if you don't need them.

Answer (score 7):

In java 8 I prefer to use a stream to convert an iterable to an array:

```
StreamSupport.stream(yourIterable.spliterator(), false).toArray(String[]::new)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use Guava's [FluentIterable](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html) :

```
FluentIterable.from(Splitter.on(":").split(mystring)).toArray(String.class)
```

Answer (score 2):

Without Guava, you could convert an `Iterable<String>` to an array with something like this

```
public static <String> String[] toArray(Iterable<String> itr) {
    ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String t : itr) {
        ret.add(t);
    }
    return ret.toArray(new String[]);
}
```

It’s a bit hard to write a generic version of this function due to the [myriad issues with generic arrays in Java,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java) so tread lightly.

Answer (score 0):

In guava you can convert it as Follows

```
 String test= "Welcome to java world";
 Iterable<String> tokens=Splitter.on(" ").split(test);
 String array[]=Iterables.toArray(tokens,String.class);
```

If you just want to access the Iterator elements like an array then no need to convert. You can directly access these elements by index

e.g

```
 System.out.println(Iterables.get(tokens,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question says "Convert Iterator to Array", answers only explain how to convert Iterable to Array.

So, to convert Iterator to Array with Guava you can use `Iterators.toArray(Iterator<? extends T> iterator, Class<T> type)`.

Answer (score 0):

I truly agree with @rec's answer: *Don't use fancy libraries if you don't need them*.

But, I strongly recommend reading Guava's splitter [documentation](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained#splitter):

Because java builtin splitter may has some tricky behaviors..

For example, suppose you have trailing commas or successive commas in your input.
What will be returned after split?

- `null`
- `""`
- (discarded)

;)

Comment: Errorprone suggest to use `Splitter` instead of `String.split`, see https://errorprone.info/bugpattern/StringSplitter